# Karate API: Checking if a number contains a decimal point

Tags: karate

Is there a way to check in Karate API to see if a number contains a decimal point?

I need to for example check that the key 'Price' ends in '.5'.  So the the 'Price' must end in '.5'  e.g 22.5 or 22222.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used this and it seems to work

```
* string aa = response.options[11].price
    And match aa contains "#regex .+[.5]+"
```

Any other/better way is welcome